# .htaccess rewrite multiple query string as path

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I've searched for this question but I only come across really specific
answers that seem difficult to tailor to my specific needs.

Let's say the URL I'm attempting to rewrite is this:

```
http://example.com/longterm/home/test.php?id=1&title=London-fire-burns-down
```

I want to rewrite it so that it appears as this:

```
http://example.com/longterm/home/1/London-fire-burns-down
```

Added question.

will the $_GET['id'] still work after rewriting in php

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww This question is clearly about **application _development_**. (?) And the use of mod_rewrite (which is what is required here) is a programming discipline. The WebApps stack is solely for the use of 3rd party web applications and I don't see how this would be on-topic for the Unix & Linux Stack either? However, it would probably be on-topic on the Webmasters Stack - where there is an overlap with these type of questions.

Comment: @user82217 - Also see this from 2009: [Apache configuration/.htaccess questions (esp. mod_rewrite): SO or SF?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283033/608639)

Comment: @jww Yes, seen that one and several others that deal with this argument. And the general conclusion is that these questions are considered on-topic for SO. However, there is a certain amount of overlap between SO, Webmasters and SF in this area. But having spent some time on SF, I would say that this question would be off-topic on SF. A URL rewriting / `.htaccess` question is likely to get unconditionally closed as a duplicate of the [catch-all rewriting quide](https://serverfault.com/q/214512/49157) (whether it is covered by that "guide" or not).

Answer (score 0):

> I want to rewrite it so that it appears as this:
>   `http://example.com/longterm/home/London-fire-burns-down`

You've kind of got it backwards... you change the URL in your application to appear as `/longterm/home/London-fire-burns-down` and then use mod-rewrite in `.htaccess` to internally rewrite it back to `/longterm/home/test.php?id=1&title=London-fire-burns-down` (the actual URL / filesystem path).

So, you now have a URL like `/longterm/home/London-fire-burns-down` that needs to be rewritten. Try something like the following in the `.htaccess` file in the document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(longterm/home)/([^/.]+)$ /$1/test.php?id=1&title=$2 [L]
```

The `[^/.]+` pattern matches any "title" that does not contain a slash or dot. By preventing a dot being matched, we avoid a rewrite loop (ie. it won't match the rewritten URL: `/longterm/home/test.php`).

However, my concern is that the `id=1` attribute is also dependent on the title and should change also? If this is the case then this information will also need to be included in the public URL somehow. eg. `/longterm/home/1/London-fire-burns-down` or `/longterm/home/1-London-fire-burns-down`, etc.

---

**UPDATE:** To incorporate the `id` attribute as stated in your *updated* question, change the `RewriteRule` to:

```
RewriteRule ^(longterm/home)/(\d+)/([^/.]+)$ /$1/test.php?id=$2&title=$3 [L]
```

> I am not querying backward. Please read the query properly.

If the "old" URLs are already indexed by search engines then you can include a *redirect* that redirects the old URL to the new (pretty) URL. (But note that the URLs in the application *must* have already been changed to show the new (pretty) URL.)

The following *redirect* would need to go *before* the above rewrite. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)&title=([^/.&]+)
RewriteRule ^(longterm/home)/test\.php$ /$1/%1/%2? [R,L]
```

The `%1` is a backreference to the first captured group in the *CondPattern* (ie. the *id*) and likewise `%2` is a backreference to the second group (ie. the *title*).

The `?` (question mark) on the end of the `RewriteRule` *substitution* removes the query string from the redirected request.

Note that this is currently a temporary (302) redirect. Change it to a permanent (301) only when you are sure it's working OK in order to avoid browser caching problems.

### Summary

Bringing this together we have something like:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Canonical redirect (in case the old URLs are indexed)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)&title=([^/.&]+)
RewriteRule ^(longterm/home)/test\.php$ /$1/%1/%2? [R,L]

# Rewrite "pretty" URL to filesytem URL
RewriteRule ^(longterm/home)/(\d+)/([^/.]+)$ /$1/test.php?id=$2&title=$3 [L]
```

Comment: I formatted the question but your solution is not working. Yes as you told, /longterm/home/1/London-fire-burns-down is required. I am not quering backward. Please read the query properly.